# Dynamic checkboxes and selectionboxes

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I know how to create dynamic checkboxes by

```
foreach($data as $row){ 
echo"<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"auswahl[]\" value='$row[0]'> Type: $row[1]"; }
```

but I would like to add to each checkbox a selectionbox (For each checkbox the same selectionbox). My Question is, how can I achieve that such that I know later which selectionbox corresponds to which checkbox?

Comment: You could set the key using an incrementing variable - `name=\"auswahl[$i]\"` & `<select name=\"linked_select[$i]\">`

Answer (score 0):

To send arrays of data you add `[]` to the input name. Since checkboxes don't always send (Thanks Marcin!) All you have to do is set a key for the array like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="auswahl[0]" />
<select name="auswahl_select[0]">...</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="auswahl[1]" />
<select name="auswahl_select[1]">...</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="auswahl[2]" />
<select name="auswahl_select[2]">...</select>
```

when that gets submitted you have:

```
Array
(
    [auswahl] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123,
        [1] => 456,
        [2] => 789,
    ),
    [auswahl_select] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123,
        [1] => 456,
        [2] => 789,
    )
```

The key of [0] in the auswahl and the key of [0] in the auswahl_select are related fields.

If you want you can also specifically specify the array keys like this:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="auswahl[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" />
    <select name="auswahl_select[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]">...</select>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

or incremented like this

```
<?php $i = 0 ?>
<?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="auswahl[<?php echo $i ?>]" />
    <select name="auswahl_select[<?php echo $i++ ?>]">...</select>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the first example you provided is incorrect - unchecked checkboxes are not sent to the server and the keys are recalculated. Here is an example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ycy-3pd If you run that code and submit the form (without changing the initial from state - leave it as it is) you'll see that checkboxes' keys no longer corresponds to the keys of selects. The second example is ok.

Comment: Oh I forgot that forms don't send unchecked checkboxes. Thanks @MarcinKrawiec! I'll fix the code